# asp.net trust level error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I deployed an asp.net mvc application and everything worked except for my Gallery page that streams pictures using flickr api. I get the following error.

Security Exception
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I went into my web.config file and changed

```
 <location allowOverride="true">
 <system.web>     
    <trust level="Full">
```

And then the site will not run at all, I get the following error

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using
     location allowOverride="false"
from an inherited configuration file.

Source Error:

```
 </customErrors>-->

 <trust level="Full" />
    <pages>
 <controls>
```

The webpage is oneotacycles.com

Any thoughts? Thanks very much!!

Comment: It looks like Flickr is trying to make a cache on the server, have you checked that particular folder has write permissions?

Answer (score 0):

As above, it looks like Flickr is trying to make a cache on the server, have you checked that particular folder has write permissions?

This may help, http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=24550

> Inside the constructor for the Flickr
>   class there is a call that tries to
>   load the default settings from the
>   configuration file (i.e. web.config).
>
> If you are running in a restricted
>   security environment (such as a hosted
>   web site with an ISP) then you might
>   not be allowed to put new config
>   sections inside a web.config file so
>   when it parses the file a security
>   exception is thrown. It will do this
>   anytime you create an instance of the
>   Flickr class.

Comment: I dont see any references to Flickr in the web.config file? where do i edit the settings?

Comment: Hmm, I dont know too much about the API having only used it once. But have a look into its caching, see if there is a cache folder being created and if so make sure that has write permissions.